# Handling JSON Webhook in JAVA Google App Engine

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, webhooks

I am trying to handle a JSON webhook in a Java app that is running in Google App Engine. Right now I am just attempting to post that data into datastore so I can verify it is there.

Here is my current code:
    Key storeKey = KeyFactory.createKey("10k", "static");
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(10000);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(req.getInputStream());
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    stringBuilder.append(scanner.nextLine());
}
String body = stringBuilder.toString();
Date date = new Date();
Entity store = new Entity("10k", storeKey);
store.setProperty("Date", date);
store.setProperty("Body", body);
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
datastore.put(store);
```

It works for a normal POST. But it does not work for a JSON webhook.

Any suggestions were to go? So far googling for it hasn't taken me very far.